# Отображение картинки в ImageView полученной из ссылки

Tags: java, android, json, imageview

Делаю приложение, которое получает JSON с сервера. Вид его следующий:

```
[
  {
     "id": 1,
     "typeOfOrganization": "Администрации",
     "created_at": 1462233600000,
     "url": "https://...../images/icon.png"
   },
   {
    "id": 2,
    "typeOfOrganization": "архив",
    "created_at": 1462233600000,
    "url": "https://.../images/icon.png"
   }

]
```

Где в url хранится абсолютный путь к картинке. Этот JSON я успешно получаю:

```
private class OrgMeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, OrgDTO[]> {
        @Override
        protected OrgDTO[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
            template.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            OrgDTO[] result = template.getForObject(Constans.URL.GET_PUBLIC_ORG_ITEM, OrgDTO[].class);
            return result;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(OrgDTO[] orgDTO) {
        List<OrgDTO> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < orgDTO.length; i++) {
            data.add(orgDTO[i]);
        }
        adapter.setData(data);
    }
}
```

В листе data приходят данные:

[image]
Разметка такая:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TEST"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

В dto классе созданы соответствующие сеттеры и геттеры:

```
package com.spravka.dto;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import java.util.Date;

public class OrgDTO {


public OrgDTO() {

}

private int id;
private String typeOfOrganization;
private Date created_at;
private String url;

public Bitmap getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
    this.image = image;
}

private Bitmap image;

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
}
```

В адаптере прописал:

```
  public void onBindViewHolder(OrgViewHolder holder, int position) {
        OrgDTO item = data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
    }
 public static class OrgViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CardView cardView;
    TextView title;
    ImageView imageView;

    public OrgViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        imageView = (ImageView) imageView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }
}
```

Подскажите, как и где теперь мне из ссылки получить Bitmap и проставить его в ImageView?

Answer (score 4):

Господи, зачем столько текста когда весь ваш вопрос сводится к одному: "как в андройде отобразить картинку в ImageView из url?". И решение гуглится за 5 минут. Вот наиболее популярные библиотеки которые созданы специально для этой задачи (а так же кеширования, некоторых трансформаций изображения и других популярных действий): [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

Самый простой вариант это наверное Picaso:

```
Picasso.with(holder.imageView.getContext())
        .load(item.getUrl())
        .into(holder.imageView);
```

Comment: Я это прекрасно понимаю,что вопрос сводится к одному, но я спрашиваю еще каким образом и где мне достать из data url

Comment: @R.Skidan, нет, вы этого не спрашиваете.

Comment: @R.Skidan не спрашиваете, да и вроде как даже сами делаете: `OrgDTO item = data.get(position);`

Answer (score 1):

Ну во-первых, делай это всё через `RecyclerView`.

Пропиши собственный `RecyclerViewAdapter`(уроки есть в инете).

После этого из класса получай ссылки и вставляй с помощю `Picasso`.

Недавно сам `JSON` с картинками парсил: [пример на github](https://github.com/sergon146/Song)

Comment: Если внимательно посмотреть на код адаптера в вопросе, то, вроде, предельно ясно, что и так используется `RecycleView`